# Displaying the video by using cv2 at wxpython panel

Tags: python, opencv, wxwidgets

I try  to display the  videocapture by using cv2 in the top panel of the wxpython.I resized the video by 640 x 480 . Finally i run the code and i got output like  1/10 part of the actual  video at the top left corner.video can't display it's actual frame, only  partially displaying ...
Thanks in Advance..

```
import wx

import cv2


class MainWindow(wx.Panel):

 def __init__(self, parent,capture):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    self.inputBox = wx.TextCtrl(self)
    mainSizer.Add(self.inputBox, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

    # video
    videoWarper = wx.StaticBox(self, label="Video",size=(640,480))
    videoBoxSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(videoWarper, wx.VERTICAL)
    videoFrame = wx.Panel(self, -1,size=(640,480))
    cap = ShowCapture(videoFrame, capture)
    videoBoxSizer.Add(videoFrame,0)
    mainSizer.Add(videoBoxSizer,0)

    parent.Centre()
    self.Show()
    self.SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer)


class ShowCapture(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self, parent, capture, fps=24):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, (0,0), (640,480))

    self.capture = capture
    ret, frame = self.capture.read()

    height, width = frame.shape[:2]

    parent.SetSize((width, height))

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromBuffer(width, height, frame)

    self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.timer.Start(1000./fps)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.NextFrame)


def OnPaint(self, evt):
    dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
    dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0)

def NextFrame(self, event):
    ret, frame = self.capture.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.bmp.CopyFromBuffer(frame)
        self.Refresh()


capture = cv2.VideoCapture('/media/ubuntu/OPEN CV/ongc_video/new_18_video.mkv')

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None,-1,'HGA Count',size=(400, 400))
panel = MainWindow(frame,capture)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: what kind of video? What OS? What version of {wx}python?

Comment: it is the .mkv  format video

Comment: ubuntu OS and wx(4.1.0) python 3.6 version